# .dockerignore failed in subdirectories with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerignore

My project directory:

```
market/
    |--.dockerignore
    |--Dockerfile
    |--index.js
    |--package.json
    |--package-lock.json
    |--market
docker-compose.yml
```

Inside my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  market:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./market/Dockerfile
```

And in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY /market/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY /market/. ./
CMD ["ls"]
```

In my .dockerignore:

```
index.js
```

Why when I run `CMD ["ls"]`, index.js still exist?

```
dockertest-market-1  | Dockerfile
dockertest-market-1  | index.js
dockertest-market-1  | node_modules
dockertest-market-1  | package-lock.json
dockertest-market-1  | package.json
```

Comment: That's not expected to work. Which documentation were you looking at that indicated it should work? https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/#dockerignore-files

Comment: I change from `.dockerignore` to `Dockerfile.dockerignore` and it works, thank you.